# How to launch IDP-initiated SSO for a SAML-enabled Connected App?

Tags: apex, connected-apps, single-sign-on

I have a SAML-enabled connected app configured for a 3rd party service provider to be used by community users (SF is IdP).

[image]

However, I can't expose SF's native app launcher as this community is under certain brand guidelines, so I have to build a custom button that redirects to the app's **IdP-Initiated Login URL**.

[image]

Can I avoid hardcoding this URL somehow? I currently have this in a VF controller that redirects.

```
public AppLauncherController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://community.example.com/idp/login?app=0sp000000000000');
        ref.setRedirect(true);        
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Hoping there's a better way launch the SSO, or construct the URL (eg., with built-in Apex classes, SOQL, LWC library)? `Site` can provide the domain and path prefix, but the app's `ServiceProvider` id (`0sp...`) is a little troublemaker.

Comment: not sure if this is possible in your case, but do you think you can query the object : SamlSsoConfig to get the url that you are looking for ?

Comment: @Philippe no, that object gives you SAML config in Setup > Single Sign-On Settings (where the current sf org is the service provider). The SAML settings in question are located in Setup > Manage Connected Apps (where the current org is the IdP)